# Cluster time-series data while preserving contiguous groups

Tags: r, time-series, clustering

I have a dataset in which a variety of values are measured at a series of times, and I have some distance function that will calculate dissimilarity between these measured values. For example,

```
d <- data.frame(t = round(seq(0, pi, length.out = 12), 2))
d$x <- round(sin(d$t), 2)
d$y <- round(d$t * 0.5 + 1, 2)
dissim <- function(x1, x2, y1, y2) {
  sqrt((x1 - x2)^2 + (y1 - y2)^2)
}
d
     t    x    y
1  0.00 0.00 1.00
2  0.29 0.29 1.15
3  0.57 0.54 1.28
4  0.86 0.76 1.43
5  1.14 0.91 1.57
6  1.43 0.99 1.71
7  1.71 0.99 1.86
8  2.00 0.91 2.00
9  2.28 0.76 2.14
10 2.57 0.54 2.29
11 2.86 0.28 2.43
12 3.14 0.00 2.57
```

I want to group/cluster these observations using the dissimilarity metric, with the caveat that **clusters should consist of observations contiguous in time**. In this example, if I asked for 4 groups, I'd probably want `1:3, 4:6, 7:9, 10:12`.

The application is identifying 4 seasons from weekly measurements of environmental data. I've seen a variety of similar questions, but none have answers.

Answer (score 4):

This paper might be relevant to you: [Clustering of Time Series Subsequences is Meaningless](http://www.cs.ucr.edu/~eamonn/meaningless.pdf) - it very convincingly shows that clustering of *subsequences* does not work. Since separating the year into weeks is a pretty arbitrary construct, I expect that clustering weekly data will not work the way you want it to.